# Error when creating database using DBCA

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, ubuntu

I'm using Oracle Database 12c R2 on my Elementary OS 5.0. The install is complete without any error. Then I create listener and it started just fine.
[image: listener is ok]
When I create database using dbca it shows warning

> ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact

( when I run tnsping 127.0.0.1 it returns OK (0 msec) )
After I click ignore, it shows this error
[image: error catalogging]

and the log is

```
[Thread-70] [ 2019-07-26 16:27:42.193 WIB ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:988]  Log RMAN Output=
[Thread-70] [ 2019-07-26 16:27:42.193 WIB ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:988]  Log RMAN Output=Recovery Manager: Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on Fri Jul 26 16:27:42 2019
[Thread-70] [ 2019-07-26 16:27:42.193 WIB ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:988]  Log RMAN Output=
[Thread-70] [ 2019-07-26 16:27:42.193 WIB ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:988]  Log RMAN Output=Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
[Thread-70] [ 2019-07-26 16:27:42.764 WIB ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:988]  Log RMAN Output=
[Thread-70] [ 2019-07-26 16:27:42.765 WIB ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:988]  Log RMAN Output=RMAN> 
[Thread-70] [ 2019-07-26 16:27:42.861 WIB ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:988]  Log RMAN Output=RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
[Thread-70] [ 2019-07-26 16:27:42.862 WIB ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:988]  Log RMAN Output=RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
[Thread-70] [ 2019-07-26 16:27:42.862 WIB ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:988]  Log RMAN Output=RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
[Thread-70] [ 2019-07-26 16:27:42.862 WIB ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:988]  Log RMAN Output=ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact
[Thread-70] [ 2019-07-26 16:27:42.877 WIB ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:988]  Log RMAN Output=
[Thread-70] [ 2019-07-26 16:27:42.878 WIB ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:988]  Log RMAN Output=RMAN> 
[Thread-70] [ 2019-07-26 16:27:42.878 WIB ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:988]  Log RMAN Output=echo set on
[Thread-70] [ 2019-07-26 16:27:42.878 WIB ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:988]  Log RMAN Output=set echo off;
[Thread-70] [ 2019-07-26 16:27:42.878 WIB ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:1031]  hasError is true
[Thread-70] [ 2019-07-26 16:27:42.879 WIB ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:1037]  ERROR TRACE DETECTED
[Thread-70] [ 2019-07-26 16:27:42.879 WIB ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:1044]  m_errHdlr=null
[Thread-70] [ 2019-07-26 16:27:42.879 WIB ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:1068]  FATAL ERROR DETECTED
[Thread-70] [ 2019-07-26 16:27:42.879 WIB ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:1132]  Notifying writer to proceed because m_bInterrupted=falsebNotify=truem_bReaderDone=truem_bFatalErrorOccured=true
[Thread-63] [ 2019-07-26 16:27:42.892 WIB ] [RMANEngine.executeImpl:1333]  Completed wait from reader
[Thread-63] [ 2019-07-26 16:27:42.892 WIB ] [RMANEngine.executeImpl:1348]  Calling done as got exception
[Thread-63] [ 2019-07-26 16:27:42.892 WIB ] [RMANEngine.done:1654]  Done called
[Thread-63] [ 2019-07-26 16:27:42.895 WIB ] [RMANEngine.executeImpl:1375]  GOT FATAL Error=Recovery Manager: Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on Fri Jul 26 16:27:42 2019
Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
RMAN> 
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact
RMAN> 
echo set on

[Thread-63] [ 2019-07-26 16:27:42.895 WIB ] [RMANUtil.catalogBackup:741]  Error while cataloging RMAN Backups: Cannot get RMANUtil
[Thread-63] [ 2019-07-26 16:27:42.896 WIB ] [RmanRestoreDatafilesStep.executeImpl:171]  exception renaming datafiles oracle.sysman.assistants.util.rmanEngine.RMANFatalErrorException: Error while cataloging RMAN Backups
[Thread-63] [ 2019-07-26 16:27:42.896 WIB ] [BasicStep.configureSettings:383]  messageHandler being set=oracle.sysman.assistants.util.InteractiveMessageHandler@6f449889
[Thread-70] [ 2019-07-26 16:27:42.901 WIB ] [RMANEngine.run:841]  Return Value from readSqlOutput=null
[Thread-63] [ 2019-07-26 16:27:42.896 WIB ] [BasicStep.configureSettings:383]  messageHandler being set=oracle.sysman.assistants.util.InteractiveMessageHandler@6f449889
[Thread-63] [ 2019-07-26 16:27:42.906 WIB ] [StepContext$ModeRunner.run:2961]  Error while cataloging RMAN Backups
oracle.sysman.assistants.dbca.backend.RmanRestoreDatafilesStep.executeImpl(RmanRestoreDatafilesStep.java:172)
oracle.sysman.assistants.util.step.BasicStep.execute(BasicStep.java:278)
oracle.sysman.assistants.util.step.BasicStep.callStep(BasicStep.java:330)
oracle.sysman.assistants.dbca.backend.CloneRmanRestoreStep.executeImpl(CloneRmanRestoreStep.java:391)
oracle.sysman.assistants.util.step.BasicStep.execute(BasicStep.java:278)
oracle.sysman.assistants.util.step.Step.execute(Step.java:135)
oracle.sysman.assistants.util.step.StepContext$ModeRunner.run(StepContext.java:2941)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And the dbca closed. I'm still new to oracle DB and self-taught, so how do I solve this?

Comment: Is Ubuntu a supported OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Elementary OS is not supported, Find the supported OS on.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/ladbi/operating-system-checklist-for-oracle-database-installation-on-linux.html#GUID-E5C0A90E-7750-45D9-A8BC-C7319ED934F0

I'd suggest to use a Virtual machine instead of your machine directly, this should help to try different configurations which may not be possible directly from your machine.

Answer (score 0):

For lost contact, check the hostname configured in Listener.

You can then check which IP is that host name resolving to.

For trial, just modify your hosts file and map localhost, system name and the FQDN to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: it's actually not the oracle db's problem, it was compatibility issue, I changed my OS to OEL6 and it actually installed fine without any problem.